# Unable to copy to memorystream from gzipstream

Tags: .net-core

I want to compress a binary file in memory using `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`. For this, I am using the following method

```
public byte[] Encrypt()
{
    var payload = GetPayload();
    Console.WriteLine("[!] Payload Size: {0} bytes", payload.Length);

    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(payload))
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        return resultStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But while `.CopyTo`, I am getting **System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support reading.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "inverse" your logic: create GZipStream over empty MemoryStream and copy your original content into this gzip stream:

```
using var compressedData = new MemoryStream();
using var gzip = new GZipStream(compressedData);
originalUncompressedStream.CopyTo(gzip); // <- "magic" happens here
gzip.Flush();

// and "rewind" result stream back to beginning (for next reads)
compressedData.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Read the question once again

Comment: Ooops. Fixed my answer.

Comment: originalStream ??

Comment: your source (uncompressed) data. renamed